# Seeing if it is in the list or not

Tags: python, list

im having problems with Homework and i have to create a list of animal names then you enter it and it says if its in the list or not.
this is what i have so:

```
List = ("Chicken","Cow","Pig","Dog","Cat","Horse","Donkey","Monkey","Rabbit",
        "Snake")

num = input("please enter a name of an animal: ")

for num in range(0,len(List),9):
    if num == List:
        print("thats in the list")
    else:    
        print("thats not in the list")
```

but when i start the code i enter the real name and it says its not in the list but it keeps saying that every time i run it and put it in the answer! Please help me

Comment: Either you accept input of animal names and make a list or input an animal name and check whether it exists in the list or not. If you try to do both at once, you may end up with such error.

Comment: `num` is a number, `List` a list, so they two can never be the same. You should name the name `name` not `num`.

Comment: look which numbers `range(0,len(List),9)` contains.

Comment: `List` is no list by a tuple.

Comment: Really...? "im having problems with Homework"? There are probably hundreds of examples of doing a search on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You probably haven't seen the `in` statement in use:

```
List = ("Chicken","Cow","Pig","Dog","Cat","Horse","Donkey","Monkey","Rabbit", "Snake")

num = input("please enter a name of an animal: ")

if num in List: # List isn't a very nice name
     print("thats in the list")
else:    
     print("thats not in the list")
```

Comment: @Kid2016: Please change the name of the `List`  variable because this name says nothing about the content and the data isn't even a `list`. `animals` might be a fine name.

Comment: @Kid2016: Ah, "idiot" is such a hard word. One point is, that a name called `List` says nothing about the content, so reading and understanding the program is unnecessary complicated. The second point is, that it doesn't matter if it's a `list` or a `tuple` or whatsoever. If you would have bothered to read the answers and comments to your questions **and** would have tried to understand them you would have seen that your `List` is not a `list`. Who's the idiot now?

Answer (score 0):

You can quite simply check for that with one line:

```
if num in List:
```

So if you called your list `animals` you could simply do:

```
if num in animals:
    print("thats in the list")
else:    
    print("thats not in the list")
```

Comment: `List` is with capital L, so its different from `list`, and `l` is a much worse name, call it `animals`.